# How do I get the average of a number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, average

I'm so close!

I'd like to be able to console log the average length of all the rivers in an array. But when I console.log (avg) in within the function getAverageLength() I'm giving an undefined number. How would I go about getting the average?

```js
function createRiver(name, continent, lengthInKilometers) {
  return {
    name: name,
    continent: continent,
    lengthInKilometers: lengthInKilometers,
    logRiver: function() {
      console.log(" The " + this.name + " river is " + this.lengthInKilometers + " kilometers long. ")

    },
    isLongerThan: function(name) {
      return this.lengthInKilometers < name.lengthInKilometers;
    }
  }
}

var rivers = [
  createRiver("Amazon", "South America", 6575),
  createRiver("Danube", "Europe", 2850),
  createRiver("Ganges", "Asia", 2704),
  createRiver("Mekong", "Asia", 4350),
  createRiver("Mississippi", "North America", 3730),
  createRiver("Nile", "Africa", 6650),
  createRiver("Volga", "Europe", 3530),
];

function getAverageLength() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i in rivers) {
    total += rivers[i].lengthInKilometers;
  }
  var avg = total / rivers.lengthInKilometers;
  console.log(avg)
}

getAverageLength()
```

Comment: I may assume, you messed things up somewhat with auto replacement at some point: `var avg = total / rivers.length`

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide by `rivers.length`:

```js
function createRiver(name, continent, lengthInKilometers) {
  return {
    name: name,
    continent: continent,
    lengthInKilometers: lengthInKilometers,
    logRiver: function () {
      console.log(" The " + this.name + " river is " + this.lengthInKilometers + " kilometers long. ")
    },
    isLongerThan: function (name) {
      return this.lengthInKilometers < name.lengthInKilometers;
    }
  }  
}

var rivers = [
  createRiver("Amazon", "South America", 6575),
  createRiver("Danube", "Europe", 2850),
  createRiver("Ganges", "Asia", 2704),
  createRiver("Mekong", "Asia", 4350),
  createRiver("Mississippi", "North America", 3730),
  createRiver("Nile", "Africa", 6650),
  createRiver("Volga", "Europe", 3530),
];

function getAverageLength() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i in rivers) {
    total += rivers[i].lengthInKilometers;
  }
  var avg = total / rivers.length; //fix this
  console.log(avg)
}

getAverageLength();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is   `var avg = total / rivers.lengthInKilometers;` as at the end of the loop `rivers.lengthInKilometers` does not exists you need to create another variable to keep track of how many items were processed.

Or you can use `rivers.legth` property to know exactly how many items does the `rivers` array have on it.

As your array `rivers` has several items on it you need an index to access a specific item on the array like `rivers[0]` from there you can acccess a property inside of the first item of `rivers` array like `rivers[0].lengthInKilometers` as `lengthInKilometers` is not part of the `rivers` array you were getting a `NaN` result `Not a Number` .

```js
function createRiver(name, continent, lengthInKilometers) {
  return {
    name: name,
    continent: continent,
    lengthInKilometers: lengthInKilometers,
    logRiver: function() {
      console.log(" The " + this.name + " river is " + this.lengthInKilometers + " kilometers long. ")

    },
    isLongerThan: function(name) {
      return this.lengthInKilometers < name.lengthInKilometers;
    }
  }
}

var rivers = [
  createRiver("Amazon", "South America", 6575),
  createRiver("Danube", "Europe", 2850),
  createRiver("Ganges", "Asia", 2704),
  createRiver("Mekong", "Asia", 4350),
  createRiver("Mississippi", "North America", 3730),
  createRiver("Nile", "Africa", 6650),
  createRiver("Volga", "Europe", 3530),
];

function getAverageLength() {
  var total = 0;
  var items = 0;
  for (var i in rivers) {
    total += rivers[i].lengthInKilometers;
    items++;
  }
  var avg = total / items;
  console.log(avg)
}

getAverageLength()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need .length: `var avg = total / rivers.length;`

Also you might want to look into prototype and reduce

Your longerThan was wrong too

```js
function River(name, continent, lengthInKilometers) {
  this.name = name;
  this.continent = continent;
  this.lengthInKilometers = lengthInKilometers;
}
River.prototype.logRiver = function() {
  console.log(" The " + this.name + " river is " + this.lengthInKilometers + " kilometers long. ")
};
River.prototype.isLongerThan = function(otherRiverName) {
  return this.lengthInKilometers < rivers.find(({name}) => name === otherRiverName).lengthInKilometers 
};

var rivers = [
  new River("Amazon", "South America", 6575),
  new River("Danube", "Europe", 2850),
  new River("Ganges", "Asia", 2704),
  new River("Mekong", "Asia", 4350),
  new River("Mississippi", "North America", 3730),
  new River("Nile", "Africa", 6650),
  new River("Volga", "Europe", 3530),
];

function getAverageLength() {
  const total = rivers.reduce((sum, {lengthInKilometers}) => sum + lengthInKilometers, 0)
  const avg = total / rivers.length;
  console.log(avg.toFixed())
}

getAverageLength()
rivers.find(({name}) => name === "Amazon").logRiver()
console.log(rivers.find(({name}) => name === "Amazon").isLongerThan("Ganges"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAverageLength() {
  var total = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i in rivers) {
    total += rivers[i].lengthInKilometers;
    ++counter;
  }
  var avg = total / counter;
  console.log(avg);
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.